# std::vector erase() not working as intended

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to erase specific elements from a vector of OrderPair while iterating, but it doesn't work as I expect it to. I'm trying to delete every `OrderPair` with `id` (first) that equals `customer_Id`. I do the following:

```
for(std::vector<OrderPair>::iterator i = source_Orders.begin(); i != source_Orders.end();)
{
      if((*i).first == customer_Id)
      {
          dest_Orders.push_back(*i);
          i = source_Orders.erase(i);
      }
      else
      {
          i++;
      }
 }
// definition of OrderPair
typedef std::pair<int, Dish> OrderPair;
// definition of OrderPair
enum DishType{
    VEG, SPC, BVG, ALC
};
// definition of OrderPair
class Dish{
private:
    const int id;
    const std::string name;
    const int price;
    const DishType type;
};
```

When the iterator is pointing at an element that fits the `if` condition, (I can see when debugging that it points to the correct element), the command `dest_Orders.push_back(*i);` is working as intended, then I'm trying to erase the element which I moved to `dest_Orders`, and keep going with the next iteration. However, the result is a removal of the last element in the vector `source_Orders`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's something you are not showing us.

```
class Dish{
private:
    const int id;
    const std::string name;
    const int price;
    const DishType type;
};
```

I'm guessing that you originally got an error saying that you can't assign `Dish` because the members are `const`. So you added an assignment operator that does nothing. Yay, it now compiles.

Unfortunately, `vector` depends on the assignment operator actually doing what it says on the tin, because it uses assignment to move the elements around when you erase something in the middle.

Comment: You are absolutely right. So what can I do this case? I need to have an empty operator= for the reason you mentioned, so it will work consistently.

Comment: Don't make the members const, or don't use `vector`. Also, assignment operator should do assignment.

Comment: I would have done it, but this is the class that was given to me, and I'm nont allowed to change it. And I'm assuming that the operator= is removed for a class with const members (the compilation error I got was that no operator= exists for Dish), otherwise I worldn't have to implement an empty one.

Comment: If you can't change it, then your options are a) not use `vector` or b) add a level of indirection (e.g., use `pair<int, shared_ptr<Dish>>`). Defining an empty `operator=` is almost never a good idea. The data members are immutable, so attempting to modify them *should* not compile.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use vector and pair<int, Dish>. it's kind of a work in university.

Comment: And it has to be a vector of pairs?

Comment: Yes, I got a filed in class which is vector of OrderPair.